# How to change background colors of a div by moving the range input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanted to change background colors using the range input slider. I am stuck at this step, how to match the value of the slider with the objcect key therefore with the value that's in it.

```html
<div>
<input class="input-range" type="range" value= "0" min="0" max="5"/>
<span class="range-value"></span>
</div>
<div class="color-box"></div>
```

```css
  .input-range {
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
    outline: none;
}

.color-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: "#FFA957";
}
```

```js
var colors = {
  1: "#FFA957",
  2: "#FFAD5E",
  3: "#FFB165",
  4: "#FFB46B",
  5: "#FFB872",
};

var colorBox= $(".color-box"),
 range = $(".input-range"),
  value = $(".range-value");

value.html(range.attr("value"));

range.on("input", function () {
  value.html(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code.

- Get the value(Color Index) specified from the slider input.
- Get the specific attribute from colors object using colors[attributeKey].
- Change the background-color using value of the selected Key.

```js
var colors = {
  1: "#4e37bf",
  2: "#754b70",
  3: "#FFB165",
  4: "#bf3653",
  5: "#FFB872",
};

var colorBox= $(".color-box"),
 range = $(".input-range"),
  value = $(".range-value");

value.html(range.attr("value"));

range.on("input", function () {
  value.html(this.value);
  var colorIndex = this.value;
  console.log(colorIndex)
  $(".color-box").css("background-color", colors[colorIndex]);
});
```

```css
  .input-range {
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
    outline: none;
}

.color-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: "#FFA957";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input class="input-range" type="range" value= "0" min="0" max="5"/>
<span class="range-value"></span>
</div>
<div class="color-box"></div>
```

Comment: Yes! That is it! Thank you!